# Is {{asset('css/app.css')}} the same as {{mix('css/app.css')}} in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to Laravel and just wanted to ask if `{{asset('css/app.css')}}` the same as `{{mix('css/app.css')}}` in Laravel.

Also, I have done some research and the articles I have read say they are the same but anyways decided to ask from you guys.

Comment: Why not try them out?

Comment: It's same but use mix() if you are using versioning. The url will be different.

Comment: @AbidRaza no, they are definitely not the same.

Comment: Yeah. the functioning is different, but the purpose is same. mix() will load the versioned output.

Comment: @AbidRaza no.. one prefixes an app url and the other suffixes a version id, completely different and they are usually used together.

Comment: My point is, will the asset load, if he is using versioning?. Yes!.

Comment: @AbidRaza i still don't get what you're on about, you'd want to use both with versioning and only asset() without it.  mix() will throw an error otherwise, just delete your misleading comments...

Comment: I said if you are using versioning.

Comment: @AbidRaza, dost please can you explain what versioning means in simple words. Please it is very important for me :)

Answer (score 4):

It's pretty easy to test these, `artisan tinker` is an interactive console.

`mix()` suffixes a version id and will only work if you have a mix manifest (used for versioning front end assets).  `asset()` prefixes your app url.

Both should be used for displaying an absolute url to a versioned asset:

**Tinker output:**

```
>>> (string) mix('js/app.js')
=> "/js/app.js?id=68390ee698d5dd6a7283"
>>> (string) asset('js/app.js')
=> "http://site.test/js/app.js"
>>> (string) asset(mix('js/app.js'))
=> "http://site.test/js/app.js?id=68390ee698d5dd6a7283
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, just great but, you know, I have read a bit about versioning and as far as I understood it means updating or what please can you explain in simple words. I hope for your answer :)

Answer (score 4):

Asset is a helper to get the path to the file you are using as parameter but in mix also includes a version number, to help prevent caching of assets.

asset()
The asset function generates a URL for an asset using the current scheme of the request (HTTP or HTTPS):

> {{asset('css/app.css')}}

mix
The lovely creators of Laravel Mix, put in the common webpack configurations and you can add more custom configurations if you wish.

This is especially wonderful for people that want to use webpack, but feel like configuring webpack is too difficult. Or maybe they wanted to use ES2016 but saw some complicated article about loaders and modules.

Laravel Mix allows you to use a single line to describe what you want and it'll use it's preconfigured settings to process it properly.

You Can Visit this link:- [#method-asset](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-asset)

click here more about mix:-[#mix](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mix)

Answer (score 1):

No they are not the same.

Using the command `asset()` basically points the real file on the server from public dir of the app using your domain, e.g. if your site was called `myawesomesite.com` then using `{{asset('css/app.css')}}` will generate the following url: http://myawesomesite.com/css/app.css

Using the `mix()` commands finds the versioned/compiled output from webpack (or gulp) and correctly generates the correct url.

Read more about compiling assets (css/js) here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mix#versioning-and-cache-busting